# ReactJS Project, Source of the Image property returns CORS Failure

Tags: reactjs, image, src, cross-origin-read-blocking

Need bit of a help with my React JS Application as I am bit of a newbie to React.

I am fetching url for an image from the DB and pass it as a prop to the Card-Layout page.`<img className="card__img" src={product.img} alt="product-img" />`
But this does not work & shows the CORB error `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response *https://unsplash.com/photos/1ObeMBhLi0k* with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.`

I have handled CORS with respect to Express.JS but having issues with React. I have tried with package "http-proxy-middleware" resolve this but did not work. URL is in the form of "https://unsplash.com/photos/1ObeMBhLi0k"

Any solution could any of you suggest?

Answer (score -1):

When loading React (or other libraries that might throw errors) from a CDN, add the `crossorigin` attribute to your `<img>` tags

Also ensure the CDN responds with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:` * in HTTP header

Comment: Hi Kamel, Thank you the suggestion but I tried it out but still did not work. "<img className="card__img" src={product.img} alt="product-img" crossOrigin="Anonymous" />". Still getting the error "Access to image at 'https://unsplash.com/photos/1ObeMBhLi0k' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." Is this a CDN issue entirely?